# Initialize variable as function which return value

Tags: javascript, callback

I define some callBack-function :

```
function callBack (){
 alert('callBack');
}
```

I pass this callback in another function :

```
myFunction (callBack);
```

In `myFunction` i want to init my local variable as `callBack` and execute it in one case

```
var todo = null;
function myFunction (callBack){
  if (typeof callBack === "function") {
        todo = callBack();
  }
}
// later in code 

if (todo != null) todo();
todo = null;
```

But If my `callBack` is function which return some value, for example `return true;` my `todo` variable won't be function, but will be as returning value type.

How can i figure it out to init `todo` variable as `function` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign todo = callBack(); invoke callback function, you can try:

```
todo = callBack;
```

Comment: and what about case when callBack has some input parameters?

Comment: when invoke: if (todo != null) todo(); in todo pass params!